# Error while getting data from firebase with an arraylist

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

So i've been doing a proyect that recieves a list of groups, then once you click on one group you can send messages, after sending a message i change the group in firebase so it has the message stored inside of the group, the thing is that after sending a message the Arraylist that i have gets a Fatal exception, i know the reason, it's because its an Arraylist of strings and now i'm sending it a hashmap so it can't convert, the thing is that i don't know how to recieve a hashmap like an arraylist and then display it like the arraylist.

The error is the next one:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Any idea on how to change from an Arraylist to a Hashmap and then get the list of groups?

here is the code where i get the arraylist right now:

```
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String,String>> gruposGT = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, String>>() {};
            
            ArrayList<String> kk = new ArrayList<>(snapshot.child("Groups").getValue(gruposGT).keySet());

            GroupsList.clear();
            GroupsList.addAll(kk);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Reference being a DatabaseReference and GroupsList just a new Arraylist

Answer (score 0):

so instead of having an arraylist getting it, i did it with an iterator, here is how i did it:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
            Iterator iterator = snapshot.child("Groups").getChildren().iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                set.add(((DataSnapshot)iterator.next()).getKey());
            }
            GroupsList.clear();
            GroupsList.addAll(set);
```